# ESP8266 + Micropython: Why do I keep getting the same value with periodic i2c reads?

Tags: accelerometer, esp8266, micropython, mpu6050

I am writing some simple code using [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/) running on a Digistump Oak, which is basically an ESP8266 breakout board.  I'm trying to understand the behavior that I see when performing periodic reads of the sensors via i2c.

The following code (which reads the value of the `ACCEL_XOUT_H` and `ACCEL_XOUT_L` registers) works just fine:

```
>>> from machine import Pin, I2C
>>> bus = I2C(scl=Pin(2), sda=Pin(0))
>>> while True: 
...     h, l = bus.readfrom_mem(0x68, 0x3b, 2)
...     print (-((((h<<8)+l)^0xFFFF) + 1) if (h & (1<<7)) else (h<<8)+l)
```

(That print statement is just performing the conversion from two's complement.)

As expected, that prints out values from the accelerometer that change in approximately real time as I move the imu around.

But if I introduce a delay into the loop, such as...

```
>>> import time
>>> from machine import Pin, I2C
>>> bus = I2C(scl=Pin(2), sda=Pin(0))
>>> while True: 
...     h, l = bus.readfrom_mem(0x68, 0x3b, 2)
...     print (-((((h<<8)+l)^0xFFFF) + 1) if (h & (1<<7)) else (h<<8)+l)
...     time.sleep(1)
```

...I see some very strange behavior.  The values returned by the i2c read operation continue to remain the same for many iterations after the imu has changed orientation.  I'm at a loss as to what is going on here: the i2c read operations read from the registers on the imu, which according to the documentation are updated at the sampling rate, which in a default configuration is going to be 1Khz.  I don't see anything in the code or data path that could be latching or caching these values somehow.

This is the documentation on the accelerometer registers, as found in the [Register Map and Descriptions](http://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/MPU-6000-Register-Map1.pdf) document:

> These registers store the most recent accelerometer measurements.
>   Accelerometer measurements are written to these registers at the
>   Sample Rate as defined in Register 25.
>
> The accelerometer measurement registers, along with the temperature
>   measurement registers, gyroscope measurement registers, and external
>   sensor data registers, are composed of two sets of registers: an
>   internal register set and a user-facing read register set.  The data
>   within the accelerometer sensors’ internal register set is always
>   updated at the Sample Rate. Meanwhile, the user-facing read register
>   set duplicates the internal register set’s data values whenever the
>   serial interface is idle.

Since I'm sleeping between read calls, I'm pretty sure the i2c serial interface is idle by any definition, and I don't see anything else seems relevant to this behavior.

Do you have any suggestions as to what could be going on here?

Comment: Hi @larsks, Could you please try to send I2C.start() at the begining of your loop and an I2C.end() before going to sleep? I think the problem is that your external device just misses some of the first data sent by the ECU

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! This project is now but a memory lost to the mists of time, but I'll keep that in mind next time I try something like this :).